# A quick way to rewrite variables with quotations marks

Tags: r, dplyr, rename

I have this dataset

```
   > dput(head(data, 10))
structure(list(ID = c("01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", 
"01", "01", "02"), GR = c("RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", 
"RP", "RP", "RP", "RP"), SES = c("L", "L", "L", "R", "R", "R", 
"V", "V", "V", "L"), COND = c("NEG-CTR", "NEG-NOC", "NEU-NOC", 
"NEG-CTR", "NEG-NOC", "NEU-NOC", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-NOC", "NEU-NOC", 
"NEG-CTR"), `P3(400-450).FCz` = c(-13.733750856001, -11.0706676917232, 
-8.4719202003519, -5.04318152659785, -6.25375875400145, -7.0474968134059, 
-11.6312151716924, -11.1438413285935, -3.99591470944713, 8.71618523084192
), `P3(400-450).Cz` = c(-9.75024624896264, -8.42427447113084, 
-5.61886494275071, 0.73152672768007, 1.11453058993788, -2.25104720773472, 
-5.16524399006139, -5.53112490175437, 0.621502123415388, 10.0972150696175
), `P3(400-450).Pz` = c(2.65626156135631, 3.37360619561252, 5.4043480635031, 
19.5226358864568, 18.5017390789352, 11.7844254386573, 11.8802266972569, 
12.1053426662461, 12.955441582096, 13.9718285231429), `LPPearly(500-700).FCz` = c(-11.2145748677083, 
-13.9481657323772, -12.0047623683783, -4.24372139176794, -7.38414465678688, 
-6.61221718491095, -11.7785042972793, -9.14927207125904, -7.58190508537766, 
14.2438131545118), `LPPearly(500-700).Cz` = c(-8.14861856277773, 
-11.7645758007163, -9.16726244915301, 0.918751423320568, -0.674372568935879, 
-2.47425935490564, -5.96429031525769, -5.10918437158799, -2.81732229625975, 
18.1277616996079), `LPPearly(500-700).Pz` = c(3.4315211013568, 
-1.55179922542943, 1.13509020104859, 16.3120391015512, 14.1694182774958, 
9.04781409226351, 8.23981597718437, 9.51261484648731, 9.42367409925817, 
20.6284861844249), `LPP1(500-1000).FCz` = c(-7.774797181711, 
-8.40872060176111, -7.03235376576925, -0.65010821749741, -3.24350263682843, 
-2.84832379590422, -5.67295796971287, -4.3918290080777, -2.96652960658775, 
12.5228696634748), `LPP1(500-1000).Cz` = c(-5.0379636708446, 
-6.36865552801825, -4.54670193355435, 4.05493850786385, 2.67516303169366, 
1.02479302810681, -0.774461731301161, -0.650009462761383, 1.14010250644923, 
15.0856583318757), `LPP1(500-1000).Pz` = c(4.67200616533014, 
1.75888442936359, 2.49276476951357, 13.8997702651793, 13.2135623121441, 
9.51479768101391, 9.99385579756163, 11.1212652173052, 10.6989716871958, 
15.4011622649207), `LPP2(1000-1500).FCz` = c(-0.397250087672501, 
1.01519755373062, -1.17300033366376, 0.663115370014327, -1.72160165493474, 
0.0540027107377267, -0.198736254963744, -3.16101041766438, 0.895992279831378, 
9.21248347391488), `LPP2(1000-1500).Cz` = c(2.91913936481813, 
1.85489998202138, 0.694393606954545, 3.95694572160701, 2.36649557381131, 
2.71292196345657, 2.96437294922766, -2.12913230708907, 2.94619035115619, 
10.0673617448764), `LPP2(1000-1500).Pz` = c(8.38141924882334, 
4.88842858528025, 5.0594399581601, 3.88831364571248, 5.83201076558185, 
3.65113189260335, 6.28027312932027, 5.24535230966772, 7.68162285335806, 
8.55827491190151), `LPP2(1000-1500).POz` = c(9.61455213192824, 
7.21299011910717, 6.1861244061312, 6.46723813995257, 7.25962635499353, 
7.92952342178602, 7.91468942320841, 9.94838815736199, 10.2186482048953, 
5.76901446016799)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
>
```

Where as you could see there some variable with annoying quotations. I scripted down this code to get rid of them

```
data <- data %>% 
  dplyr::rename("P3(400-450).FCz" = P3Fcz,       
                "P3(400-450).Cz" = P3cz, 
                "P3(400-450).Pz" = `P3(400-450).Pz`,      
                "LPPearly(500-700).FCz" = `LPPearly(500-700).FCz`,  
                "LPPearly(500-700).Cz" = `LPPearly(500-700).Cz`, 
                "LPPearly(500-700).Pz" = `LPPearly(500-700).Pz`, 
                "LPP1(500-1000).FCz"  = `LPP1(500-1000).FCz`,
                "LPP1(500-1000).Cz" =  `LPP1(500-1000).Cz`, 
                "LPP1(500-1000).Pz" = `LPP1(500-1000).Pz`, 
                "LPP2(1000-1500).FCz" =  `LPP2(1000-1500).FCz`,  
                "LPP2(1000-1500).Cz"  =  `LPP2(1000-1500).Cz`,  
                "LPP2(1000-1500).Pz"  = `LPP2(1000-1500).Pz`,  
                "LPP2(1000-1500).POz" = `LPP2(1000-1500).POz`)
```

By the way I am quite sure that could there be some quicker alternatives to deal with them. Do you any suggestions about it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You may use `clean_names(data)` from `janitor`

Comment: Also, isn't the `rename` reverse i.e. `dplyr::rename(P3Fcz = "P3(400-450).FCz",       
                  P3cz = "P3(400-450).Cz",..., the other column names are just using the same value on the lhs and rhs of `=`

Comment: Yes I know. There was a typos. Sorry but thanks for you contribute as usual. By the way I am not able to find the clean_names and janitor package as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do:

```
df %>%
  rename_with(~str_remove(.x, "\\W.+\\W"))
```

To be more precise:

```
 df %>%
    rename_with(~str_remove(.x, "\\(.+\\."))
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. BTW I would like to keep between brackets values for each of them. It is just a matter to get rid of quotations marks. It was my mistake to report the first two variables name without the brackets

Comment: @mały_statystyczny do you want to keep the special characters like `(`? If so, YOU CAN NOT remove the backticks

Comment: Ok but it always possible to replace the backticks with double quotation marks `" name().name"`. That is the operations I'm interasting in

Comment: @mały_statystyczny NO you cannot. The backticks is the only way to refer to a VALID NAME with special characters. Unless you remove the special characters, you cannot neglect the backticks. its just the syntax of R. Other languages witll not accept a special character in a variable name